# Check a kernel extension is loaded

Tags: aix, kernel-extension

I have to implement a function that installs a new kernel extension in the system. Before installing the extension I want to check whether it is already installed from another location. Since I do not know the other location I cannot use the sysconfig library function.

I've checked

`truss genkex`

to see how this is done by another tool. The only system call that was a bit interesting was read_sysconfig. Unfortunately I did not find documentation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here I have an example function, that prints all loaded kernel extensions:

```
#define BUFF_SIZE       10241024U

static void testExtension() {
    void *buffer = calloc( 1, BUFF_SIZE );
    if( buffer ) {
        struct ld_info *xInfo;

        int result = loadquery(L_GETKERNINFO, buffer, BUFF_SIZE);

        xInfo = buffer;

        while( xInfo ) {
            printf( ">>>>>>> >%s< %d\n", xInfo->ldinfo_filename, result );

            uint offset = xInfo->ldinfo_next;
            xInfo = offset ? (char*)xInfo + offset : NULL;
        }

        free( buffer );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you search for is **SYS_QUERYLOAD sysconfig** operation and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/s_bostechref/SYS_QUERYLOAD.html#SYS_QUERYLOAD) you can find more information about it

> The SYS_QUERYLOAD sysconfig operation performs a query operation to
>   determine if a given object file has been loaded. This object file is
>   specified by the path field in the cfg_load structure passed in with
>   the parmp parameter. This operation utilizes the same cfg_load
>   structure that is specified for the SYS_KLOAD (SYS_KLOAD sysconfig
>   Operation) operation.
>
> If the specified object file is not loaded, the kmid field in the
>   cfg_load structure is set to a value of 0 on return. Otherwise, the
>   kernel module ID of the module is returned in the kmid field. If
>   multiple instances of the module have been loaded into the kernel, the
>   module ID of the one most recently loaded is returned.
>
> The libpath field in the cfg_load structure is not used for this
>   option.

Also you can check with this script about the objects in `odm` database.

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
    odmget -q phase=$i Config_Rules
done
```

And check the file `/sbin/rc.boot` (which may contain load of some module(s)

Comment: I have seen this function. It requires the full path of the extension or searches the extension within LIBPATH.

Comment: @MartinGäckler, check my updated answer with additional ways to check for the modules

Comment: You mean odmget? opdget is not known on my system.
I will check the file /etc/objrepos/Config_Rules. Perhaps this could be a solution. But I'm still wondering how genkex is working

Comment: Another routine I can use is loadquery with L_GETKERNINFO passed as first parameter. This is, what genkex also uses, I still have to find out, what struct has to be passed as second parameter.

Comment: According to /usr/include/sys/ldr.h loadquery expects a struct __ld_xinfo64,

Where is that structure defined?

Comment: @MartinGäckler, I found __ld_info (w//o `x`). Can you confirm

Comment: @MartinGäckler, IMHO this URL will give you idea about the structure: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/filesreference/ldr.h.html